# want to change search algorithm in custom fields

Tags: search, search-results, quicksearch

Suppose I have phone number having format as (xxx)xxx-xxxx.Is their anything in search so that I can simply search with this format which excludes brackets and characters like xxxxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standard phone number fields, that is taken care of:

- In Advanced Search, the help text shows "Punctuation and spaces are
  ignored." Formatting entered in the search is ignored and the search is done on just the digits.
- In Quick Search, enter just the digits of the phone number.

But your title mentions custom fields... Does that mean you have an alphanumeric custom field to store a phone number?  Instead of that, can you use the standard phone numbers with a different 'location'?  You can customise the list of locations at `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Dropdown Options > Location Types`

Comment: I want to change the appearance of civi crm reports when we export it to PDF.some contents are getting overlapped.
http://imgur.com/a/QRXhp

Thanks for your support.